# Cordova android volume/up button event on release not press

Tags: android, cordova

Seeing a strange (unwanted) behaviour on a ZTE A112 Android 6 with our very simple Cordova app, which is currently just listening for `volumedown/volumeup` events.  Registered the listeners after `ondeviceready`.  The event is firing on release of the appropriate button, not on press (which is what we need).  Can't seem to get to the bottom of it.

after ondeviceready:

```
document.addEventListener('volumeupbutton', volumeUpKeyHandler, false);
document.addEventListener('volumedownbutton', volumeDownKeyHandler, false);
```

Going to try on other brand phones and see if it follows or it's a handset specific thing.  If anyone has seen this before or any clues it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Cordova by default triggers on the KeyEvent.ACTION_UP (rather than ACTION_DOWN) in CordovaWebViewImpl.java, meaning that the propagated events happen when the key is released.  It looks like it does this to minimise the number of events, as ACTION_DOWN triggers a stream of events, and ACTION_UP emits a single event.

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2020 Cordova for Android still doesn't support this.

Here are the necessary changes to make this work: https://github.com/trullock/launch-pad/commit/244d67971063203491434bbd03cf91a0493eb04f

This hasn't been rigorously tested, and it's only the Android implementation.

Better than nothing!